# Is it posible to copy/paste xampp folder and make it work in another computer?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I have a xampp server in a laptop with an application running as development environment, and I need to move all the server to a new computer.

Will it work if I copy/paste the complete xampp folder from one to another, or is it needed to "install" xampp from the installation package in the new computer?

I need it to be the exact version because productive environment does not support a newer version of PHP (actual version is 5.5.11).

I already tried downgrading a xampp installation but it seems that I need to install also the xampp version that supports the PHP version.

I did not succeed on finding that specific version of PHP on surceforce.

Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: I would seriously recommend upgrading the PHP version and fix the incompatibilities in the code instead. 5.5 reach it's end-of-life 3,5 years ago. It doesn't even get security patches/updates. If it's a public facing application, it's at risk.

Comment: No it wont work! you need to reinstal xampp, and copy paste your **projects** into new xampp folder.

Comment: It may work, but I've had issues with xamp in the past, I would suggest you give a look at docker, it is worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MagnusEriksson. It is not a public application, I'm aware of those risks. It is in an internal server only accessed by company employees.

Comment: I would still recommend bumping the PHP version. It will make your life way easier since you won't need to search for deprecated versions of the software etc. Or you could do as @Nathanael suggested. Set up the environment in a docker container, vagrant or something like that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've figured out it can be done. I installed the newest version then copied all config folders from my actual version along with all my files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider to use VirtualBox or/and Docker for future :)